# QwtPlot setAxisScale, how it works?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qwt

I subclassed `QwtPlot` like:

```
class RealPlot : public QwtPlot {
public:
    RealPlot () {
        ...
        setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, -5, 5);
    }
    void addPoint(Point p) {
        ...
        setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, min, max);
    }
}
```

And I would like to rescale the (horizontal axis of) plot every time a new point is added. So I call `setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, min, max);` just after the point is added to the curve.

The problem is that the plot is not being rescaled. The call to `setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, -5, 5);` in the constructor does rescale the plot. But `setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, min, max);` does not. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QwtPlot::replot is missing to make your changes happen.
In case of startup you always run into an initial replot - that's why it is working there.